# Compare two columns in different workbooks

Tags: excel, vba

I would appreciate if I can get help in creating this macro. I have two workbooks, and want to compare the specific column from 1st workbook, Ex: Column H with next work book, Ex: column A. After comparison highlight the matching cells in 1st workbook. I have tried below script for comparison, it is executing successfully, but not seeing any result.

```
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, w(), i As Long
    Dim r As Range, myCol As String
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    Set ws2 = Workbooks("workbook.xlsx").Sheets(1)
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^([a-z]|[a-h][a-z]|[a-i][a-v])$"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Do
            myCol = InputBox("Enter Column")
        Loop While Not .test(myCol)
    End With
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .comparemode = vbTextCompare
        For Each r In ws1.Range(myCol & "1", ws1.Range(myCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If Not IsEmpty(r) And Not .exists(r.Value) Then
                   ReDim w(0): w(0) = r.Row
                   .Add r.Value, w
            Else
                   w = .Item(r.Value)
                   ReDim Preserve w(UBound(w) + 1)
                   w(UBound(w)) = r.Row
                   .Item(r.Value) = w
            End If
        Next
        For Each r In ws2.Range("a1", ws2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If .exists(r.Value) Then
                For i = 0 To UBound(.Item(r.Value))
                     ws1.Range(myCol & .Item(r.Value)(i)).Offset(, 1).Resize(, 23).Value = _
                     r.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 23).Value
                Next
            End If
        Next
    End With
    Set ws1 = Nothing: Set ws2 = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The script copies columns A to  X for matching rows from workbook.xlsx, it does not highlight them. To do that you need to add the line  ws1.Rows(.Item(r.Value)(i)).EntireRow.Interior.Color = vbYellow inside the For i = 0 To UBound(.Item(r.Value)) loop.

Comment: I am choosing column H from workbook 1, script gets executed but doesn't show any result, even copying does not happening. I'm using Office 365, any syntax should be modified according to Office versoin?

Comment: What data type is column H, text, numeric, date ? Give an example of a cell in column H and the corresponding cell in column A of workbook.xlsx that it should match

Comment: It is text, i have verified after copying some content from column A of second workbook to column H of first workbook, I'm getting rest of the columns other than column A copied to workbook 1

Comment: So is it working and the copying happening now ?

Comment: Yes, copying is working now, but the output is not as expected. I need only the matched valued to be copied to 1st worksheet in column (ex. column i)

Comment: Which column on 1st worksheet do you want the matched value to be copied to ?. i is not a column, it is an numeric index to an array of row numbers that match the key.

Comment: I'm expecting to highlight the match in column H in 1st worksheet,

Answer (score 0):

Try

```vb
Sub test()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet, w(), i As Long, n As Integer
    Dim r As Range, myCol As String, wbname As String, msg As String
    
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
   
    Dim myworkbooks As Variant, mycolors As Variant
    
    ' workbooks to compare
    myworkbooks = Array("Workbook1.xlsx", "Workbook2.xlsx", "Workbook3.xlsx")
    mycolors = Array(vbYellow, vbGreen, vbBlue)
    
    ' select column
    With CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
        .Pattern = "^([a-z]|[a-h][a-z]|[a-i][a-v])$"
        .IgnoreCase = True
        Do
            myCol = InputBox("Enter Column")
        Loop While Not .test(myCol)
    End With
    
    ' build dictionary
    With CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        .comparemode = vbTextCompare
        
        For Each r In ws1.Range(myCol & "1", ws1.Range(myCol & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
            If IsEmpty(r) Then
              ' skip empty cells
            Else
                If Not .exists(r.Value) Then
                   ReDim w(0): w(0) = r.Row
                   .Add r.Value, w
                Else
                   w = .Item(r.Value)
                   ReDim Preserve w(UBound(w) + 1)
                   w(UBound(w)) = r.Row
                   .Item(r.Value) = w
                End If
            End If
        Next
                
        ' compare and highlight match
        For n = 0 To UBound(myworkbooks)
            Debug.Print "Opening " & myworkbooks(n)
            msg = msg & vbCrLf & myworkbooks(n)
            
            Set ws2 = Workbooks(myworkbooks(n)).Sheets(1)
        
            For Each r In ws2.Range("a1", ws2.Range("a" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
                If .exists(r.Value) Then
                    
                    For i = 0 To UBound(.Item(r.Value))
                         ws1.Range(myCol & .Item(r.Value)(i)).Interior.color = mycolors(n)
                    Next
                    
                End If
            Next r
        Next n
        
    End With
    Set ws1 = Nothing: Set ws2 = Nothing
    MsgBox "Completed scanning" & msg, vbInformation
End Sub
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks, it worked perfectly. If I need to compare more than 1 file is there way to do it? I would have maximum of 3 files with the main file to compare one after the another and different color for each WB. Ex: If cell matches in WB2 = Yellow, WB3=Green, WB4=Blue, like that.

Comment: @Moorthy Will all the workbooks be open when the macro is run ?

Comment: Yes, I will keep open when the macro is running.

Comment: @Moorthy - see update. Change arrays myworkbooks and mycolors definitions to suit.

Comment: It worked without any error, but it does highlight only the matching value from WB2, not from other workbooks

Comment: @Moorty Check the values don't have trailing spaces. Create 3 test files with known good data and test with them before using on real data.